# show/hide div on the bases of which box div clicked in Vuejs. check image for better understanding

Tags: vue.js

[image]

This is an image of table i created(ignore dates in header)

***Functionality I want***

when a user click on a specific box dialog open and get some value which will decide whether to put tick or cross in that box. Let's say i clicked on a box in first column(27/07/2020) and third row(asdf)
then tick should be shown in that box.

***Here is table I'm creating***

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead class="table_header">
            <tr >
              <th scope="col" class="text-center table_th" >Medications</th>
              <template v-for="head in table_headers_data" >
                <th scope="col" class="text-center table_th" >{{head.day}} {{head.date}}</th>
              </template>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <template v-for="item in active_medications" >
              <tr :key="item.uuid">
                <th class="cust-border" scope="row">{{item.title}}</th>
                
                <td v-for="(date_item, index) in table_headers_data"   @click="boxClicked(item,date_item)" :key="index" >
//here is code where i am trying to show tick or cross on the basis of user input in that box and 
                  <div  v-show="selected_box==date_item.day+item.uuid+'-tick'" class="text-center" >
                    <v-icon  color="green">mdi-check</v-icon>
                    <!-- <v-icon v-if="showCross==true" color="red">mdi-close</v-icon> -->
                  </div>
                  <div  v-show="selected_box==date_item.day+item.uuid+'-cross'" class="text-center" >
                    <!-- <v-icon v-if="showTick==true" color="green">mdi-check</v-icon> -->
                    <v-icon color="red">mdi-close</v-icon>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </template>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

boxClicked function just get object of an item of medicine and data related to dates information.. then i store that data in firebase. problem i don't know how to show tick/cross in that specific box. its like a user take medicine or not on that date. if it takes medicine according to data i have to show tick or cross in that box corresponding to that medicine and date.

***here is boxClicked function code***

```
   boxClicked(medicine,date_data){
    this.checkbox_dialog      = true;
    this.administered_dialog  = true;
    this.medicine_detail.med_date = date_data.date;
    const today   = new Date();
    //const date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    //const dateTime = date +' '+ time;
    this.medicine_detail.med_time   = time;
    this.medicine_detail.med_day    = date_data.day;
    this.medicine_detail.med_uuid   = medicine.uuid;
    this.medicine_detail.user_email = this.user_email
    /*console.log(this.medicine_detail)
    let as = date_data.day+medicine.uuid;
    console.log('as = '+as)*/
  },
```

***save_medicine_record function***

this function is called when someone click on box and dialog open and user select it's value and click OK button . on click of OK button this function is called.

in the response of axios request i'm show tick/cross in that perticular box

```
    save_medicine_record(status){
    let api_token = this.user.api_token
     axios.post('api/save_medicine_record?api_token='+api_token,this.medicine_detail)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response = ')
        console.log(response)
        
        if(this.medicine_detail.status=='non_administered'){
          console.log('in respose cross')
          this.selected_box=this.medicine_detail.med_day+this.medicine_detail.med_uuid+'-cross'
          // this.showCross = true;
        }  
        else if(this.medicine_detail.status=='administered'){
          console.log('in respose tick')
          this.selected_box=this.medicine_detail.med_day+this.medicine_detail.med_uuid+'-tick'
          //this.showTick = true;
        }
        //this.table_headers_data=[];
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
        /*this.snackbar_error = true
        this.snackbar_text = err.response.data.message*/
      })
  },
```

I tried to give id to the div in  like  ***:id="date_item.day+item.uuid"***
and other way i tried is in above code.
Everything is working fine when i store data in firebase and get result from axios i want to put tick or cross in that specific location..

***Problem now facing***

after many tries i am able to show tick/cross on the basis of user input but then when i try to enter value in other box then it removes previous clicked box and show just one box value(tick/cross icon div).

I also tried to create data variables dynamically in a thinking to give that v-if true and false. but unable to reach that point.

Please please guide me how to achieve functionality because i spent many days on it.

***I posted this question 10 days ago but did not get any solution so that is why i am posting it again***

***Pics of dialogs when a box is clicked***

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to post the code for `boxClicked`

Comment: @Daniel_Knights please check updated question

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of selected boxes, Try this for tick and same for cross

```
//you can use a Map() [--dictionary] object here
this.selected_box_array.push(this.medicine_detail.med_day+this.medicine_detail.med_uuid+'-tick')

<!-- <v-icon v-if="showTick==true && selected_box_array.indexOf(date_item.day+item.uuid+'-tick')" color="green">mdi-check</v-icon> -->
```

Comment: it's not like that. i do not have array of selected boxes . user click on one box and then dialog open and get user value on that dialog there is OK button which will trigger save_medicine_record function.i am uploadin images of dialog in question please check it.

Comment: how do you track individual item unless you have some place to store their state?